# Android app, upload and install success. But nothing displayed on my device

Tags: android, eclipse

My android phone is Galaxy S 3.  android system 4.1.2
No app can be run through eclipse when I attach the phone to the computer.
They all showed that"

```
[2013-08-07 15:11:43 - test005] Android Launch!
[2013-08-07 15:11:43 - test005] adb is running normally.
[2013-08-07 15:11:43 - test005] Performing com.example.test005.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-08-07 15:11:43 - test005] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-08-07 15:11:45 - test005] Uploading test005.apk onto device 'aa1974fe'
[2013-08-07 15:11:45 - test005] Installing test005.apk...
[2013-08-07 15:11:57 - test005] Success!
[2013-08-07 15:11:57 - test005] Starting activity com.example.test005.MainActivity on device aa1974fe"
```

But eventually nothing happened on my phone.??
And the app can run on my other phone. what's the matter?? 
Galaxy s3. Deverloper options activated

Comment: Maybe you have configured your application for other versions or have not activated Developer Option in your device.

Answer (score 3):

Check your manifest file you must have this action and relative category tag in your main activity's `<intent-filter>` tag

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: I have that. Actually, my app can run through eclipse on my other android phone. But on my Galaxy s3 . It displays nothing. And I'm sure I activate my developer option USB degugging.

Comment: If you have done every required setting from your end and still having problem then please read this : http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 0):

in the above logcat your application is just deployed .its not starting .. run it again and it will work perfectly as when app starts the console shows this type of message

ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.flowers_1800/.HomeTabActivity }